# Creating a delete function to remove items from HTML list and the array which populates list items?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling

```javascript
// create array populate with 4 list items
let arr = ['apples', 'pears', 'blackberries', 'blueberries'];

// create a function 
const populateList = array => {
    
    // create a for loop to run through list items
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        
        // for each list item, create a list item element
        let listItem = document.createElement('li');
        
        // populate list item with array item in iteration
        listItem.innerHTML = array[i];

        // create span element
        // let spanElement = document.createElement('span');

        // append list item element with span item containing unicode: \u00D7
        listItem.innerHTML += "<span class='close'>\u00D7</span>";
        
        // append unordered list with list item as child element
        document.getElementById('itemList').appendChild(listItem);

    }

    return console.log(document.getElementById('itemList').innerText);
   
}

function updateList () {

    let selectedItem = [document.getElementById('input').value];

    if (selectedItem == "") {

        alert(`Please, insert an item!`);

    } else {

        arr.push(document.getElementById('input').value);

        document.getElementById('input').value = "";

        return populateList(selectedItem);

    }

}

populateList(arr);

document.querySelectorAll('.close').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', deleteFunction => {

        for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) 
          console.log(spanElements[i].parentNode.innerText.slice(0, -1));

        // Problems here: my click event triggers all list items to
        // repopulate. How can I isolate a click press event so when
        // I click on HTML I can retrieve a single value and remove
        // that matching item from my array and repopulate the HTML
        // list without the value removed?

    })
  })
```

Comment: Plz format properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `id` to `span` element so that you can get the reference to clicked `element` from event argument. After the click event you need to remove entry from array, clear the div container and then call populate list along with `addEventListerner` as old listeners will be removed.

*Note - Ideal way would be too remove element directly and don't re-render the elements again and again. this way you will not be repainting and re-initialising the event listeners.*

```js
// create array populate with 4 list items
let arr = ['apples', 'pears', 'blackberries', 'blueberries'];

// create a function 
const populateList = array => {
    
    // create a for loop to run through list items
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        
        // for each list item, create a list item element
        let listItem = document.createElement('li');
        
        // populate list item with array item in iteration
        listItem.innerHTML = array[i];
        listItem.id = `list-${array[i]}`;

        // create span element
        // let spanElement = document.createElement('span');

        // append list item element with span item containing unicode: \u00D7
        listItem.innerHTML += ("<span id='close-"+array[i]+"' class='close'>\u00D7</span>");
        
        // append unordered list with list item as child element
        document.getElementById('itemList').appendChild(listItem);

    }
}

function updateList () {

    let selectedItem = [document.getElementById('input').value];

    if (selectedItem == "") {
        alert(`Please, insert an item!`);
    } else {
           arr.push(document.getElementById('input').value);
      document.getElementById('input').value = "";
      return populateList(selectedItem);
    }

}

const removeElement = (srcElementId) => {
  const clickedElementId = srcElementId;
  const id = clickedElementId.split('-')[1];

  // removes data from array
  for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i] === id) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

const addClickEventListener = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.close').forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      removeElement(event.srcElement.id);
      
      document.getElementById('itemList').innerHTML = '';
      
      populateList(arr);
      addClickEventListener();
      
   });
  });
}

populateList(arr);
addClickEventListener();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Click 'x' to remove elements - </h1>
<div id='itemList'></div>

</body>

</html>
```